# Replace element in ArrayList of objects [Kotlin]

Tags: kotlin, arraylist

I know I can replace an element inside an ArrayList

```
list.set(index, "new string")
```

But let's say I have an ArrayList with objects.

```
list.set(index,(myObject("Hello", "world")))
```

How can I replace "Hello" or "World" in that object within the ArrayList?
If there is another data structure that I can to use to achieve this, then it would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your elements is mutable, you can change the value of element

Example:

```kotlin
class MyObject {
  var first: String = ""
  var second: String = ""
}


list[index].first = "Bye"
```

Comment: Instantly a fan of mutable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like this:

```
data class MyObject(var st1: String, var st2:String)

fun main() {
    val index = 0
    val list = arrayListOf<MyObject>(MyObject("hello", "world"))
    list.getOrNull(index)?.st1 = "something"
}
```